# Conditional statements inside resize not firing everytime when conditions are met

Tags: javascript, jquery, resize

Im trying to fire a function once on resizing. The problem is the conditional statements are not being executed everytime for some reason. the code is

```
var old_width= $(window).width(); 
$(window).on('resize.3col',function(e){ 
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer=setTimeout(function(){
    var nw= $(window).width();
    if((nw <= old_width) && (nw <= '940') &&   (nw >= '915') ){
      appendList('resize.3col');
    }
    old_width= nw;
  } , 500);
});
```

the reason im using settimeout is because I want to get the new width, if I dont use it the new width is the same as old width which I don't want. If I dont use settimeout, the conditions work.
EDIT:
the conditional statements fire sometimes at other times they do not. How do I make it more smooth?

Comment: You should replace the two `$(window).width()` calls in your conditional with `nw`

Comment: Are you sure you only want to fire code when they resize from a larger size and the width falls in the 25px range?  If so your code is working as long as `timer` is declared earlier (ie: `var timer;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the same timer variable for calling the resize event with different namespaces '3col', '4col' and '5col'. Also I added if(timer) clearTimeout(timer); which improved the functionality. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see if there is any difference:

```
var $win = $(window),
  oldWidth= $win.width(),
  winResized = function(){
    var newWidth= $win.width();

    if (
      newWidth <= oldWidth &&
      newWidth <= 940 &&
      newWidth >= 915
    ){
      appendList('resize.3col');
    }
    oldWidth = newWidth;
  },
  timer;

$win.on('resize.3col',function(e){
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(winResized, 500);
});
```